# How to access global variable $menu inside a class function

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

am puzzling why can't i access the global variable `$menu` inside a php class function

```
class adminMenus {
   public function getWPdefaultmenus(){
      global $menu;
      return $menu;
   }
}
```

using this code in a plugin file and this function still return `NULL`.

**Edited**
what i am doing after @Will the Web Mechanic's answer

```
class adminMenus {
     private $getWPdefaultmenus;
     public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'getWPdefaultmenus' ) );
      }
      public function getWPdefaultmenus(){
          global $menu;
          $this->getWPdefaultmenus = $menu;
      }
    }
```

but this returns error:Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook into some action that happens after the `global $menu` has been set.

as an example:

```
class adminMenus {
   public function getWPdefaultmenus(){
      global $menu;
      return $menu;
   }
 add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'getWPdefaultmenus' ) );
}
```

Comment: still not work. what i am doing is

Comment: please check my edited question

Comment: The edited code you have above does not produce any error for me, and works as expected.